# How to scale the X-axis of matlab plot like figure2

Tags: matlab, plot

#### Undesired scale:

[image: The x-scale i dont want]

#### Desired scale:

[image: The x-scale i want]

The figure in picture 1 shows a quite strange scaling of X-axis even though it is semilogx plotting (some small data points, the red points, cannot be seen easily)
Can someone help to scale the data as exactly what picture2 does?
Thanks!

Comment: what's your current plotting code?

Comment: Show us the code. The first plot is not what matlab returns if you only do semilogx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't know if I got your question but, have you tried chaging the scale of the axes with xlim and ylim ( https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html ) ?

Comment: You can change the scale property of the X axis from linear to logarithmic. Just right-click on the axis in the figure. there's also code to do it, see https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html and https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html?searchHighlight=axis%20properties&s_tid=srchtitle#budumk7_sep_shared-XScale

Comment: your first plot (don't want) uses a linear scale instead of `semilogx`. check your command. if you want to change an axis's scale, you can use `set(gca,'xscale','log')`

Comment: yes i tried the xlim and ylim, it didnt work. But now I figured out what was wrong in my plotting. I think that I used the 'hold on' code too early, which I think will fix the x-scale. And I fixed this problem by simply putting the data with different X-sclae together in one semilogx.

Comment: And to make it more clear, which might be useful for other guys with same problem here. The orinigal codes: `semilogx(X1,Y1) ;`%X1,Y1,X2,Y2 are list% `hold on;` `semilogx(X2,Y2);` %which is wrong cuz it will only scaling X-axis based on X1,Y1 datapoints.% Modified codes: `semilogx(X1,Y1,X2,Y2);` in this case the scaling will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Codes of undesired plotting:

```
semilogx(X1,Y1);
hold on;
semilogx(X2,Y2);
```

Codes of desired plotting:

```
semilogx(X1,Y1,X2,Y2);
```

I think it is might due to the code 'hold on' will confine the plotting to the scaling of X1,Y1 only, so that when you again plot another datasets X2,Y2 with different scaling it will show something like undesired plotting, even though you use semilogx on both cases.